# Python code to break if next bits of data in binary blob don't exist

Tags: python

Simply, part of my program is to read in a series of binary data that I unpack for some external dictionary to do comparisons on. I have a binary blob being passed in as a file to read from. This little snippet looks as follows:

```
        while index < argCount:
            data = f.read(4)
            logData = logData + struct.unpack('i', data)
            index = index + 1
```

However, if there aren't 32 bits of data present left, say there are only 3 bits of data left (ie. an incorrect blob is being retrieved into the program) then how can I tell the user 'bit error, exiting'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exception handling:

```
    while index < argCount:
        try:
            data = f.read(4)
            logData = logData + struct.unpack('i', data)
            index = index + 1
        except IOError:   #or any other error you get there
            print 'bit error, exiting'
```